# Group Policy deploying printers

Tags: group-policy, printer

We moved our print server to another computer and IP. The Servers are all running Win Server 2008 R2. All clients are Windows 7 Pro 64bit.

I was under the assumption, that 'Replace' will either add a new printer to a workstation that never had that printer, OR, replace the printer with another printer.

It seems to work as replacing the printer for existing workstations, but new workstations do not get the printer. How can this be resolved? If I used the add printer first, wouldn't it duplicate workstations that already have the printer with the same printer?

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure that the Group Policy is trying to install the printer, but failing because of insufficient rights for installing untrusted drivers. (check gpresult)

Configure Point and Print so that it trusts your print server(s), or disable it all together if you want.

Comment: gpresult said it wasn't filtered out. Doesn't show error or anything regarding that policy other than it has been applied

Comment: @Markaway This does smell of a driver deployment problem. Find a machine which doesn't work and map the printer manually as an administrator. This will install the drivers - then see if GPP's works properly for that machine.

Comment: Yep. Definitely sounds like a driver issue. The Point and Print GPO is probably the solution here.